# How to use QWebEnginePage Actions [Qt5.8]

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.8

I need help on how to and when to use `QWebEnginePage::OpenLinkInNewTab` and `QWebEnginePage::OpenLinkInNewWindow` in Qt5.8 as I am completely new to Qt.

Comment: Did you read the documentation and the example or test code?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did't found any example about pageActions in qt5 , If you have some link then please let me know